# Various types of images in Java

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio, imageicon

When attemting to make a simple application which uses an image I was amazed at the large number of image types available to me. I did a search on them and whilst finding a little about them cannot work out what image is ment to be used in what circumstances.

The types of image I am confused about are Image, ImageIcon, and ImageIO.

Comment: `Image` is used mainly for graphics, `ImageIcon` mostly for labels, and `ImageIO` is just a helper class for doing i/o with images.

Comment: Is there something specific you want to do with the image?

Comment: All I wish to do is load it from a URL and display it. How would you go about modifying the image?

Comment: Take a look at [Graphics2D tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/). There's a section on working with images. You'll see they use a `BufferedImage` which is a subclass of `Image`, which I explained is what you want when dealing with graphics. The tutorial shows you how to manipulate and save the manipulated image

Comment: How does a BufferedImage differ form an Image and thanks for the link, it's just what I need :)

Comment: See [Difference Between Image and BufferedImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944825/difference-between-the-image-and-bufferedimage-in-java) - also the tutorial explains it in the first page of the Working with Images section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The only one of those that is an image is `Image`. A more powerful sub-class of `Image` is `BufferedImage`.
- An `ImageIcon` is an image based **`Icon`**.
- `ImageIO` simply helps us to read and write images, and do other things *with* images.

Be sure to check the JavaDocs for each.  It adds more details.

[Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) | [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) | [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) | [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)